# Dynamic React-Router routes

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router, react-router-redux

I want to use different routing based on some partial state, so I came up with the following:

**in my entry file:**

```
import routes from './routes.js'

ReactDOM.render(
  <IntlProvider locale={locale} messages={messages[locale]}>
    <Provider store={store} key='provider'>
      <div>
        <Router history={history} routes={routes(store)} />
      </div>
    </Provider>
  </IntlProvider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

**routes.js:**

```
export default (store) => (
  let isAuthenticated = store.getState().auth.isAuthenticated

  if(isAuthenticated) {
    return (
      <Route component={Tool}>
        <IndexRoute component={Dashboard} />
        <Route path="products" component={Products} />
      </Route>
    )
  } else {
    return (
      <Route>
        <Route component={Site}>
          <IndexRoute component={Home} />
          <Route path="pricing" component={Pricing} />
        </Route>
        <Route component={Portal}>
          <Route path="login" component={Login} />
          <Route path="register" component={Register} />
        </Route>
      </Route>
    )
  }
)
```

This works, but only if I actually refresh the page. It will **however not transition** from Home component to Dashboard component if I just login without refreshing the browser page, so I suspect the routes object is build only once at the beginning and builds up on the current state, but will not change if the state changes mid execution.

I also found https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/docs/guides/DynamicRouting.md this concerning dynamic routes but as I tried it it doesn't seem to do what I hoped or expected it to do.

Comment: React Router has this functionality built in. Please see reference: https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/tree/master/examples/auth-flow

Comment: @DanWinter-Wijntjes I can't see how this example demonstrates it. It's not about the auth flow, it's about dynamic routing, and the routes in the example seem pretty static to me.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the `onEnter` method on the route level

```
<Route name="example" path="/example" component={Example} onEnter={functionToCheckAuthorization()} />
```

With a function to check authorisation e.g.

```
function functionToCheckAuthorization(nextState, replace) {
  if (!auth.loggedIn()) {
    replace({
      pathname: '/login',
      state: { nextPathname: nextState.location.pathname }
    })
  }
}
```

Please see reference: https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/examples/auth-flow/app.js

Also see reference: https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/243 to explain the intentions behind using auth-flow as an example

Comment: Why would you post that answer after I already noted in the comment above that this is not what I want. It just happens to be the authentication part of the state in my case, but it really is just an example. I want to have different routing models based on some arbitrary value of the state.

Comment: So to clarify... You want to provide a different set of routes based on some value? If this is the case, you can do this with the method above and a bit of tweaking. auth.loggedIn() can be replaced with whatever value you need to check. React router is not designed to have state changes above it, therefore you need to decide route visibility. The common practise for React router and dynamic routing is to "... declare all your routes up front, and then validate the visitor's ability to visit them like the auth-flow example."